# Insert text, at the cursor, in a cell that already contains text (MS Excel VBA 2013)

Tags: vba, excel

For the record I have very limited experience with coding. We use Excel to document all the real time events in the day. Reports are approx 100 to 150 rows long with multiple lines in each row. Each row uses 12 merged cells and text is wrapped.

Desired Action: to insert specific text, after the cursor, in a cell that already contains text (MS 2013 Excel using VB).

The code below works except it puts the text at the top of the cell instead of at the cursor. We cannot use a text box and recording doesn't work. What code can accomplish this? Thank you!

```
Sub SuziQueue () 

    With ActiveCell 
        .Value = "<Suzi Queue... >" & .Value 
    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Value = .Value & "<Suzi Queue... >" ` ?

Comment: Excel VBA is different from Word VBA in that the **cursor position** is not discernable. If you enter a cell's contents in edit mode (either in the cell or in the formula bar) you cannot run a VBA sub procedure until you leave edit mode. You can insert text by locating other text and using that as a position for insertion but you are not going to be able to insert text at the 'cursor position'.

Comment: You could possibly intercept a change and store the original cell value in a variable then allow the change and calculate the difference then do your insertion, I am assuming this is for some sort of logging of changes to data?

Comment: Here is some info that may help you get started. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/track-changes.htm

Comment: Perhaps you protect the worksheet and unlock the column after it for text input. Then use **Worksheet_Change** event to inject the new text into the cell on the left, and ClearContents at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this example will help

- if you have the text "Test String" in ActiveCell
- you want to insert the word "New" in between the 2 words

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertText()
    Dim indx As Long, lastPart As String

    With ActiveCell
        MsgBox .Value2      'shows "Test String"

        indx = InStr(.Value2, "S")
        lastPart = Right(.Value2, indx + 1)

        .Characters(indx).Insert "New" & lastPart 'inserts "New" between "Test" & "String"

        MsgBox .Value2      'shows "Test New String"
    End With
End Sub
```

.

There might be ways to determine the cursor position in the cell using APIs

[This Microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152969) shows how to get the cursor position on the screen